# (Python) Selecting rows containing a string in ANY column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate through a dataframe  and return the rows that contain a string "x" in any column.

This is what I have been trying

```
for col in df:

     rows = df[df[col].str.contains(searchTerm, case = False, na = False)]
```

However, it only returns up to 2 rows if I search for a string I know exists there and in more rows.

How do I make sure it is searching every row of every column?

Edit: My end goal is to get the row and column of the cell containing the string searchTerm

Comment: Are you searching for a full string values or a substring? If it's the full string then do `rows  = np.where(df.values == 'x')[0]`. Don't iterate through dataframes if you can help it.

Comment: kindly share sample data with expected output

Answer (score 3):

Welcome!

Agree with all the comments. It's generally best practice to find a way to accomplish what you want in Pandas/Numpy *without* iterating over rows/columns.

If the objective is to "find rows where *any* column contains the value 'x'), life is a lot easier than you think.

Below is some data:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': range(10), 
        'b': ['x', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'x'],
        'c': [False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True],
        'd': [1, 'x', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'x', 10]
})

print(df)
   a  b      c   d
0  0  x  False   1
1  1  b  False   x
2  2  c   True   3
3  3  d   True   4
4  4  x   True   5
5  5  f  False   6
6  6  g  False   7
7  7  h   True   8
8  8  i   True   x
9  9  x   True  10
```

So clearly rows 0, 1, 4, 8 and 9 should be included.

If we just do `df == 'x'`, pandas broadcasts the comparison across the whole dataframe:

```py
df == 'x'
       a      b      c      d
0  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
4  False   True  False  False
5  False  False  False  False
6  False  False  False  False
7  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False   True
9  False   True  False  False
```

But pandas also has the handy `.any` method, to check for True in any dimension. So if we want to check across all columns, we want dimension 1:

```py
rows = (df == 'x').any(axis=1)

print(rows)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     True
```

Note that if you want your solution to be truly case sensitive like what you're using with the `.str` method, you might need something more like:

```py
rows = (df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).lower() == 'x')).any(axis=1)
```

The correct rows are flagged without any looping. And you get a series back that can be used for indexing the original dataframe:

```py
df.loc[rows]
   a  b      c   d
0  0  x  False   1
1  1  b  False   x
4  4  x   True   5
8  8  i   True   x
9  9  x   True  10
```